# Nosql file DB with pop values ability

Tags: python, database, nosql, bigdata

I am looking for a nosql file database that supports the following data format:

```
key1 -> [1, 2, 3]
key2 -> [a, b, c]
key3 -> [x, y, z]
```

With the ability to pop, so that after going through all the keys, I have values ​​in my variable

```
{key1: 1, key2: a, key3: x}
```

, and the following data remained in the database:

```
key1 -> [2, 3]
key2 -> [b, c]
key3 -> [y, z]
```

For these purposes (and for reference) redis lists are ideal: https://redis.io/commands/lpop
However, I have a lot of data, and I need a solution with storage in files and (as option) a hot cache in RAM.
MongoDB can also do this, but maybe there is another solution specifically made for tasks of this type and designed for big data?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a ranked-set you can implement it on top of embedded Ordered Key-Value Store (wiredtiger, lmdb, rocksdb...) or distributed like FoundationDB.

Here is an example implementation: https://github.com/FoundationDB/fdb-record-layer/blob/master/fdb-extensions/src/main/java/com/apple/foundationdb/async/RankedSet.java